# Story identification: medical examiner vs. alien parasite

Tags: story-identification

I need help identifying a short story that I recall reading in one of those paperback collections of award nominees that used to be common. I read it in the late 1980s or early 1990s, but, alas, if I knew which award it was nominated for, I wouldn't need to ask here. The basic plot: A medical examiner is called to the site of a mine collapse which happened during the search for a serial murderer. It turns out that both killings and the mine collapse were caused by an alien parasite, which is detected by the medical examiner in the course of an autopsy.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like Michael Shea's "[The Autopsy](http://worldsofweird.com/michael-sheas-the-autopsy/)", an absolutely terrifying story.

> The Autopsy is about, what else? an autopsy, but a weird autopsy. After a strange explosion at a mine, Dr. Winters, a veteran coroner afflicted with stomach cancer, is tasked with determining the cause of the death of the miners for insurance reasons. The mine was presumably blown up by a murder suspect and Dr. Winters’ old friend Sheriff Craven is interested in the outcome.